# Having trouble with MySQL double to date conversion

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have searched and searched for ways to do this but have found very limited information.

I have a MySQL table 'msgdb' that contains a field 'ttime' that is in the format double(25,8) (example row = 1352899856.95249200).

I need to routinely cleanup the table by removing any rows where the field 'ttime' is <= today's date -5 days.

These are the only two lines of code I could find related to double to time conversion but cannot get either to work.

```
SELECT ADDDATE(ADDDATE(ADDDATE('1899-12-31 00:00:00',FLOOR(ttime)), INTERVAL -1 DAY),INTERVAL(MOD(ttime,1)*86400)SECOND) AS TrueDate FROM msgdb

select date('1899-12-31 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL ttime * 24*3600 SECOND) as date from msgdb
```

I have tried first to display any rows that match the criteria using the code below, before I started using DELETE FROM to make sure I'm getting the correct results.

```
 $query = "select date('1899-12-31 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL ttime * 24*3600 SECOND) as date from msgdb";
 $result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['date'];
   echo '<br>';
 }
```

and also

```
 $query = "SELECT ADDDATE(ADDDATE(ADDDATE('1899-12-31 00:00:00',FLOOR(ttime)), INTERVAL -1 DAY),INTERVAL(MOD(ttime,1)*86400)SECOND) AS TrueDate FROM msgdb";
 $result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['TrueDate'];
   echo '<br>';
 }
```

but both are returning nothing.

UPDATE: Ok so by using this code:

```
$query = "select ttime from msgdb";
$result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo date('m-j-Y, H:i:s', $row[0]);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

I am able to see it convert 'ttime' field from the stored value of 1352899856.95249200 to 11-14-2012, 07:30:56.

So how would I DELETE from the table all rows where ttime is <=now - 5 days?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using 1899 as a base date? Are you a time traveller?

Comment: @tadman That was just the way I found the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring out which records have a date before a point in time should be easy:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ttime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

It might also be better to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` if you store all your times in UTC, which is the only sane way to do it.

Comment: I have no control over the format that is being stored in the table it is from a live chat routine. It is storing the datetime in the double format that looks like 1352899856.95249200

Comment: The field is in unixtime, so how would I incorporate UTC_TIMESTAMP() into DELETE FROM table WHERE ttime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY); ?

Comment: Got it. DELETE FROM from msgdb WHERE ttime <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day))

Comment: Yeah, that should be it. Wasn't clear in your question that you were dealing with raw UNIX times. That they're fractional is odd to say the least.